# Accounting for a principal component in a linear model

Tags: pca, linear-model, experiment-design

I have the following experimental design:
Gene expression was measured at 8 time points, for cells treated with a certain compound (Cd) and controls treated with water (Cd_control). The time points are 0, 2, 4, 8, 12, 24, 48, and 72 hours, where the compound was added after time point 0. Thus I have 16 samples, 8 per each treatment. (unfortunately I only have 1 replicate per each time point per treatment, but that's outside the point of this post). What I'm interested in is detecting genes that are differentially expressed between the two treatments - Cd and Cd_control.

As it turns out the compound slows down the growth rate of the cells, so at any given time point the number of cells treated with the compound is different than that without the compound. The thing is that it is very likely that the number of cells in the dish affects the expression levels of genes - at least that's what I can conclude from running a PCA and examining the loadings:
[image]

This means that I can't really correspond between the two treatments at any given time point. Ideally I'd have the cell count at each time point but unfortunately I don't have that.

So I'm wondering what would be a good way to account for that time effect. Is using the first PC:

```
gene_expression ~ treatment + PC1
```

a good way to go?